parse SQL script via python to a table for field, name, and table it comes from
I am trying to create a helpful table because we have a lot of raw tables and views with business definitions.
for example the design for my v_ods_ACT_Master would be
SELECT MBACCT AS [Account Number], ABCNAME AS [Business Name], dbo.ConvertDate(OBDTE) AS [Onboard Date]
FROM dbo.ods_ACT_Master

I want to the output to be a table like:



Field
Business Name
Table




MBACCT
Account Number
ods_ACT_Master


ABCNAME
Business Name
ods_ACT_Master


OBDTE
Onboard Date
ods_ACT_Master



ideally to create a table where I can add every one of my views so it would eventually be the end all be all key for business users.



Field
Business Name
Table




MBACCT
Account Number
ods_ACT_Master


ABCNAME
Business Name
ods_ACT_Master


OBDTE
Onboard Date
ods_ACT_Master


XYZCODE
Code 1
ods_lkup_table1


PSNDOB
Date of Birth
ods_PersonEntity



I tried to use sqlparse but while reading the documentation was not sure if it could do what I was looking for, seemed like it was more for splitting up the SELECT, FROM, and WHERE sections as opposed to reading and dissecting the select

You are probably better off looking in to a data lineage tool. As soon as things get complex with subqueries, unions, calculations using multiple fields, etc... you are biting off a lot to chew writing your own utility.

I have tried the below approach using the sqlparse
import sqlparse
from sqlparse.sql import IdentifierList as dilip_IdentifierList, Identifier as dilip_Identifier
from sqlparse.tokens import Keyword as dilip_Keyword, DML as dilip_DML
import pandas as pd

def dilip_subselect(dilip_parsed):
    if not dilip_parsed.is_group:
        return False
    for item in dilip_parsed.tokens:
        if item.ttype is dilip_DML and item.value.upper() == 'SELECT':
            return True
    return False
def dilip_extract_from_part(dilip_parsed):
    dilip_from_seen = False
    for item in dilip_parsed.tokens:
        if dilip_from_seen:
            if dilip_subselect(item):
                for x in dilip_extract_from_part(item):
                    yield x
            elif item.ttype is dilip_Keyword:
                return
            else:
                yield item
        elif item.ttype is dilip_Keyword and item.value.upper() == 'FROM':
            dilip_from_seen = True
def dilip_extract_table_identifiers(dilip_token_stream):
    for item in dilip_token_stream:
        if isinstance(item, dilip_IdentifierList):
            for identifier in item.get_identifiers():
                yield identifier.get_real_name()
        elif isinstance(item, dilip_Identifier):
            yield item.get_real_name()
def dilip_extract_select_part(dilip_parsed):
    dilip_select_seen = False
    for item in dilip_parsed.tokens:
        if dilip_select_seen:
            if dilip_subselect(item):
                for x in dilip_extract_select_part(item):
                    yield x
            elif item.ttype is dilip_Keyword:
                return
            else:
                yield item
        elif item.ttype is dilip_DML and item.value.upper() == 'SELECT':
            dilip_select_seen = True
def dilip_extract_column_identifiers(dilip_token_stream):
    for item in dilip_token_stream:
        if isinstance(item, dilip_IdentifierList):
            for identifier in item.get_identifiers():
                yield identifier.get_real_name(), identifier.get_alias() or identifier.get_real_name()
        elif isinstance(item, dilip_Identifier):
            yield item.get_real_name(), item.get_alias() or item.get_real_name()
def dilip_parse_sql_view(dilip_view_sql, dilip_table_name):
    dilip_parsed = sqlparse.parse(dilip_view_sql)[0]
    dilip_columns = list(dilip_extract_column_identifiers(dilip_extract_select_part(dilip_parsed)))
    dilip_table = list(dilip_extract_table_identifiers(dilip_extract_from_part(dilip_parsed)))[0]
    if dilip_table_name:
        dilip_table = dilip_table_name
    return [(column[0], column[1], dilip_table) for column in dilip_columns]
def dilip_define_business_key_table(dilip_view_sqls):
    dilip_records = []
    for dilip_table_name, dilip_view_sql in dilip_view_sqls.items():
        dilip_records.extend(dilip_parse_sql_view(dilip_view_sql, dilip_table_name))
    df = pd.DataFrame(dilip_records, columns=['Field', 'Business Name', 'Table'])
    return df
dilip_view_sqls = {
    'v_ods_ACT_Master': """
    SELECT MBACCT AS [Account Number], ABCNAME AS [Business Name], dbo.ConvertDate(OBDTE) AS [Onboard Date]
    FROM dbo.ods_ACT_Master
    """,
    'v_ods_lkup_table1': """
    SELECT XYZCODE AS [Code 1]
    FROM dbo.ods_lkup_table1
    """,
    'v_ods_PersonEntity': """
    SELECT PSNDOB AS [Date of Birth]
    FROM dbo.ods_PersonEntity
    """
}
dilip_df = dilip_define_business_key_table(dilip_view_sqls)
print(dilip_df)

Results:
         Field     Business Name               Table
0       MBACCT  [Account Number]    v_ods_ACT_Master
1      ABCNAME   [Business Name]    v_ods_ACT_Master
2  ConvertDate    [Onboard Date]    v_ods_ACT_Master
3      XYZCODE          [Code 1]   v_ods_lkup_table1
4       PSNDOB   [Date of Birth]  v_ods_PersonEntity


In the above I am reading and dissecting the SQL SELECT statements,
Extracting the  information like column names (Field),(Business Name), and table(Table) from each view's SQL definition.
The above code will create a structured table that maps fields to business names across multiple views.
